# Discord.js use try catch statement to handle api error

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Hello I am currently attempting to catch a discord api error with the try catch statement

However for some reason this does not work and my app still stops executing and gives me the following message

```
 There was an uncaught error DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user // Example
```

How do I catch api errors with a try and catch block and I cannot use a .catch expression after calling the function

Here is my code

```
try {
    interaction.user.send("Remember")
}
catch(DiscordAPIError) {
    console.log("Oh no")
}
```

Comment: Is there a stack trace that tells you which function call caused the error? The try catch looks fine, however you want to name the parameter error, not `DiscordAPIError`

Comment: Yes the trace tells me that the interaction.user.send function caused the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a synchronous try/catch block, you need to put it in an async function and await the promise from `interaction.user.send`:

```js
await interaction.user.send("Remember")
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your help however when I tried to add the await statement the following error accrued "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules"

Comment: @yyn79436 to enable async, use `async function [functionname]() {` at the start (replace [functionname] with a function name), and then `} [functionname]();` at the end

Comment: yes, you need to put it in an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) - make sure to read up on async/await and promises